# Use of unassigned local variable Abstract classes

Tags: c#, .net

I'm learning C# and I need some help to understand variable scopes.

I have 3 different classes, 1 base class and 2 inherited. I want to define a function which creates a new instance of the inherited classes and return it.

My code so far:

```
class Base
{
    public Base(){}
}

class Divided1 : Base
{
    public Divided1(){}
}

class Divided2 : Base
{
    public Divided2(){}
}

private Base selectType()
{
    Base base;
    string type = Console.ReadLine();

    if (type == "1")
    {
        base = new Divided1();
    }
    else if (type == "2")
    {
        base = new Divided2();
    }

    return base;
}
```

I got an error

> Use of unassigned local variable 'base'

I'm not sure why is it wrong.

Comment: Hint: What happens if `type` isn't `"1"` and isn't `"2"`?

Comment: I'm implemented it, just didnt want to litter my example code. :)

Comment: Explicitly assign it with null when declaring `Base base = null;`

Comment: Well, it seems to me there's a code path where `base` never gets set, or else the compiler wouldn't be giving you this error.